# how to get columln name from other table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two table (match and equipe)
table match contain equipe1id and equipe2id
I want to query match and get the name of equip1id and equipe2id
see below my query to do so

```
SELECT * FROM `match`,equipe where    match.equipe1id=equipe.id and match.equipe2id=equipe.id
```

table match :
id
equipe1id
equipe2id
score1
score2
date
arbitreid

table equipe:
id
nom

expected results :
matchid  name_equipe1,name_equipe2,score1,score2,date,arbitre_name

Comment: Does your `match.equipe1id` and `match.equipe2id` contains same values? Because in your query you compare against same `equipe.id`. Can you provide table schema/data and desired/actual results?

Comment: thank justinas for your answer appreciated

Comment: equipe1id and equipe2id is different but it comes from same table equipe

Comment: table match 
 # Nom Type Interclassement Attributs Null Valeur par défaut Commentaires Extra Action
 1 id Primaire int(11)   Non Aucun(e)  AUTO_INCREMENT Modifier Modifier Supprimer Supprimer 
 2 idtournoi int(11)    
 3 equipe1id int(11)    
 4 equipe2id int(11)   
 5 score1 int(11)    
 6 score2 int(11)   
 7 idArbitre int(11)  
 8 date datetime   
 9 phase varchar(20)  
 10 status varchar(20)

Comment: table match 
 
 1 id Primaire int(11)   Non Aucun(e)  AUTO_INCREMENT Modifier Modifier Supprimer Supprimer 
 2 idtournoi int(11)    
 3 equipe1id int(11)    
 4 equipe2id int(11)   
 5 score1 int(11)    
 6 score2 int(11)   
 7 idArbitre int(11)  
 8 date datetime   
 9 phase varchar(20)  
 10 status varchar(20)

Comment: sorry i dont know how to share that

Comment: Edit question, create table with rows information

Comment: ok just updated that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    m.id AS matchid,
    e1.nom AS name_equipe1,
    e2.nom AS name_equipe2,
    m.score1,
    m.score2,
    m.date,
    m.arbitre_name
FROM
    match m
    JOIN equipe e1 ON m.equipe1id = e1.id
    JOIN equipe e2 ON m.equipe2id = e2.id
```

Comment: thank u but it gave me an error about arbitre_name as you know i have table arbitre like equipe it contain name and id  so i need to get name of arbitre based on idarbitre in table match

Comment: if u have another table arbitre, it will be somthing like that :   
 `SELECT
    m.id AS matchid,
    e1.nom AS name_equipe1,
    e2.nom AS name_equipe2,
    m.score1,
    m.score2,
    m.date,
    a.name AS arbitre_name
FROM
    match m
    JOIN equipe e1 ON m.equipe1id = e1.id
    JOIN equipe e2 ON m.equipe2id = e2.id
    LEFT JOIN arbitre a ON m.arbitreid = a.id
     `